# Program to filter lines by passing them to an external program?

Tags: shell, command-line, filter

I'm looking for a program to use an external program to filter the lines of a stream - pretty much a version of `grep` that, for each line, prints or suppresses it based on whether the specified program exits with a zero exit code (like `find`'s `-exec` option).

I know that I can do this in shell by using a loop and a subshell:

```
some-program |(while read line; do
    if predicate "$line"; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done)
```

What I'm wondering is if there's a program floating around that will let me make this simpler:

```
some-program |filter predicate
# want negation as well
some-program |filter ! predicate
```

One would think that an enhanced Sed might support this, asking "does it pass on the pattern space?", but GNU Sed does not seem to have such a facility.

Is there such a program somewhere that I haven't found, or do I just need to do it in shell (or perl)?

Comment: And `predicate` is a shell command?  Are you sure you want to run a new process for every line in the file?

Comment: @alex `predicate` is a shell command, and running a new process for each line is what I'm looking for. Inefficient, but it for one-offs it'd be convenient.  I'm actually writing a full Perl script now for the immediate task, but having such a program handy for future reference would still be useful.

Comment: I'd take a look at shell functions and `eval` built-in.

Comment: You don't actually have to use a subshell; you can do `some-program | while ...; do ...; done` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is a perfectly suitable tool for this job. Just take care not to mangle spaces and backslashes.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if predicate "$line"; then printf '%s\n' "$line"; done
done
```

You could also use awk. Be sure to quote each line since it'll be passed to a shell (the snippet below puts single quotes around the line, and replaces single quotes in the line by `'\''`; `\047` is `'`). Because each command invocation goes through a shell, I expect this to be slower than the pure shell method, even if awk is likely to be faster at parsing lines. But I haven't made any benchmarks.

```
awk '{quoted=$0; gsub(/\047/, "\047\\\\\047\047")}
     !system("predicate \047" $0 "\047")'
```

Comment: printf '%s\n' "$line" is the same as echo "$line", isn't it?

Comment: @NeilMayhew Almost, but `echo "$line"` may mangle its argument in a few cases (if `$line` is `-e` or `-E` or `-n`; and with some shells it may do backslash interpolation) whereas `printf '%s\n' "$line"` reliably prints `$line` followed by a newline.

Comment: if you want to have a ”program“ called `filter`, simply create a (globally available) shell function with the desired name, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34007275/307637